# What does =~/^0$/ mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I have been learning about the Perl basics for past two days.
I'm converting a Perl script to Java program gradually. 
In the Perl script, I came across this code.

```
if( $arr[$i]=~/^0$/ ){
...
...
}
```

I know that `$arr[$i]` means getting the `i`th element from the array `arr`.

But what does `=~/^0$/` mean?

To what are they comparing the array's element?

I searched for this, but I couldn't find it.

Someone please explain me.

FYI, the `arr` contains floating values.

Comment: Sound like that perl script is an awesome piece of code. `=~ /^0$/` is a regular expression applied to the contents of `$arr[$i]`. It tries to check whether the contents is `0`.

Comment: @innaM `/^0$/` also matches `"0\n"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`if ($arr[$i]) =~ /^0$/)` is *roughly* equivalent to `if ($arr[$i] eq "0")`, but not exactly the same, as it will match both the strings "`0`" and "`0\n`".  If `$arr[$1]` was read from a file or stdin and it has not been `chomp`ed, this can be a very significant distinction.

`if ($arr[$i] == 0)`, on the other hand, will match any string beginning with a non-numeric character or a string of zeroes/whitespace which is not followed by a numeric character, although it will generate a warning if the string contains non-whitespace, non-digit characters or contains only whitespace (and warnings are enabled, of course).

Comment: "followed by a non-numeric character"?  no.  " " == 0, and "000" == 0.  also, warnings aren't dependent on just the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: @ysth: Fair points. Edited to more closely approximate reality.

Comment: It's great that you point out the important difference between this and `$arr[$i] eq "0"`, would +20 if I could!

Answer (score 9):

`^` and `$` are regex anchors which says `$arr[$i]` should begin with `0` and there is end of string immediately after it.

It can be written as

```
if ($arr[$i] eq "0" or $arr[$i] eq "0\n")
```

Comment: Whether 'even better' is better depends on how happy you are that it's true more often than the original. 'Better' is best, absent `use re`, (textual) parallelism, and the writer reckoning he may return to this test to add to the regex.

Comment: The "even better" version is a terrible idea, since it will be true when `$arr[$i]` is any non-numeric string, like "hello world".

Comment: Thanks, updated. At the end, author knows best what he put in `$arr[$i]` and whether there should be string or number.

Comment: `/^0$/` also matches `"0\n"`

Answer (score 9):

`=~` is a [binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators).

```
"Binary "=~" binds a scalar expression to a pattern match"
```

`/^0$/` on the right hand side is the [regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)

```
^        Match the beginning of the line
$        Match the end of the line (or before newline at the end)
```

And the zero has no special meaning.